# Проблема с кодировкой. В IDE работает, а в консоле нет

Tags: java

Отсылаю строки Телеграм боту. При отправке из IDE независимо от того, какая строка русская или английская - всё работает. Но если собрать jar и запускать с консоли, то приходят только текст на английском. Если отправлять на русском, то даже ответа от сервака не приходит. Я склоняюсь к мысли, что дело в кодировке UTF-8. Помогите разобраться почему так происходит. Спасибо.

```
final static String BOT_ID = "123456";
final static String CHAT_ID = "78910";
static String URL = "https://api.telegram.org/bot" + BOT_ID + "/sendMessage?chat_id=" + CHAT_ID + "&text=";

 public static void main(String[] args) throws UnsupportedEncodingException
{


    /*String text = URL + "русский текст";
    byte[] byteText = text.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
    String originalString= new String(byteText , "UTF-8");*/

    String performPost = performPostCall(URL + "русский текст");
    System.out.println(performPost);
}

public static String  performPostCall(String requestURL
       /* HashMap<String, String> postDataParams*/) {

    URL url;
    String response = "";
    try {
        url = new URL(requestURL);

        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setReadTimeout(15000);
        conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.setDoOutput(true);



        int responseCode=conn.getResponseCode();

        if (responseCode == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            String line;
            BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream(),"UTF-8"));
            while ((line=br.readLine()) != null) {
                response+=line;
            }
        }
        else {
            response="";

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return response;
}
```

Когда присутствует русский текст то сервак возвращает 400 Bad Request. А если текст английский то нет. Но это всё при запуске из консоли.

Comment: а что за консоль то?

Comment: В windows стандартная консоль. Для меня загадка почему в ИДЕ работает, а в консоле 400 ошибка. Но только при русском языке.

Comment: Java по умолчанию работает с UTF-8, а Windows с CP1251. Вам нужно сделать контроль входных параметров и преобразовывать кодировку в UTF-8, если текст задан не в ней

Comment: Вот в этом то и проблема. Как его правильно преобразовать? Пробую, а не получается.

Comment: https://toster.ru/q/11449

Comment: Это не то. Там проблема с выводом.

Comment: там описано как кодировку менять

Answer (score 0):

Получилось решить проблему вот так:

```
  String inputText = URL + "русский текст";
  InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(inputText.getBytes("UTF-8"));
  String result = getStringFromInputStream(is);

  String performPost = performPostCall(result);
  System.out.println(performPost);
```

и дополнительный метод

```
 // convert InputStream to String
private static String getStringFromInputStream(InputStream is)
    {

    BufferedReader br = null;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    String line;
    try
            {

        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {sb.append(line);}

    } catch (IOException e)
            {
    } finally {if (br != null)
            {
     try {  br.close();} catch (IOException e) {}
    }
    }

    return sb.toString();

}
```